# Micro-optimizing a linear search loop over a huge array with OpenMP: can't break on a hit

Tags: c, loops, pthreads, openmp, micro-optimization

I have a loop that takes between 90% and 99% of the program time approximately.  It reads a huge LUT, and this loop is executed > 100,000 times, so it deserves some optimization.

**EDIT:**

The LUT (actually there are various arrays that compose the LUT) is made of arrays of `ptrdiff_t` and of `unsigned __int128`.  They have to be that wide because of the algorithm (especially the 128 bit ones).  `T_RDY` is the only `bool` array.

**EDIT:**

The LUT stores past combinations used to try to solve a problem that didn't work. There's no relation between them (that I can see yet), so I don't see a more appropriate search pattern.

The single threaded version of the loop is:

```
k   = false;
for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < T_IND; i++) {
        if (T_RDY[i] && !(~T_RWS[i] & M_RWS) && ((T_NUM[i] + P_LVL) <= P_LEN)) {
                k = true;
                break;
        }
}
```

With this code, which makes use of OpenMP, I reduced the time between 2x and 3x in a 4 core processor:

```
k   = false;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(k)
for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < T_IND; i++) {
        if (k)
                continue;
        if (T_RDY[i] && !(~T_RWS[i] & M_RWS) && ((T_NUM[i] + P_LVL) <= P_LEN))
                k = true;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Info about the data used:

```
#define DIM_MAX     128

#define P_LEN       prb_lvl[0]
#define P_LVL       prb_lvl[1]

#define M_RWS       prb_mtx_rws[prb_lvl[1]]

#define T_RWS       prb_tab
#define T_NUM       prb_tab_num
#define T_RDY       prb_tab_rdy
#define T_IND       prb_tab_ind


extern  ptrdiff_t   prb_lvl [2];

extern  uint128_t   prb_mtx_rws [DIM_MAX];

extern  uint128_t   prb_tab [10000000];
extern  ptrdiff_t   prb_tab_num [10000000];
extern  bool        prb_tab_rdy [10000000];
extern  ptrdiff_t   prb_tab_ind;
```

However, the fact that I don't get an improvement of approx. 4x means that it introduces an overhead, which I guess goes from 2x to 1.5x.  Part of the overhead is unavoidable (creating and destroying the threads), but there's some new overhead due to the facts that OpenMP doesn't allow to `break` from a parallel loop and that I added an `if` to each iteration, and I would like to get rid of it if possible.

Is there any other optimization that I could apply?  Maybe using pthreads instead.

Should I bother editing some assembly?

I'm using GCC 9 with -O3 -flto (among others).

**EDIT:**

CPU: i7-5775C

But I plan to use other x64 CPUs with more cores.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200107/discussion-on-question-by-cacahuete-frito-micro-optimizing-a-linear-search-loop).

Comment: Removing the break can be: `for (...; !k && ...;...)...` ... uses for's conditional for the break.  Then you can use k= ... instead of the whole if statement.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as well as specific performance measurements.

Comment: @technosaurus  That's the first thing I tried, but OpenMP doesn't allow that kind of expression for the control of the for loop.

Comment: You _say_ it uses a lookup table (as in 1), but in fact it uses 3.  They are all the same size and probably could be combined into a single lookup table.  You could even do a bit-table so you can check 64 at a time by comparison to 0 or -1 (all false or all true)

Comment: @technosaurus That thing of the 64 comparisons at a time (T_RDY) can be a really big improvement.  I'll try that.  You could write it as an answer ;)

Comment: @Zulan I'm sorry that the construction of the LUT is not something that I would call minimal.  I could link to the code, but it's not something liked here.

Comment: Presuming that `M_RWS`, `P_LVL` and `P_LEN` aren't supposed to change during the execution of the search, you could load those extern values into local variables to ensure that they're not being constantly reloaded every loop.  If you know that `P_LEN - P_LVL` won't under- or overflow then you could precalculate that and use it in the comparison as well.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito No, you are supposed to **create** a [mcve] by reducing the code as much as possible. Not post or link the complete code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can coalesce k into bit tables and then do comparisons 64 at a time.  If an entry in the main tables change, recompute that bit in the bit table.

If different queries use different `M_RWS` or `P_LVL` or something, then you'd need separate caches for separate search inputs.  Or rebuild the cache for their current values, if you do multiple queries between changes.  But hopefully that's not the case, otherwise the all-caps names are misleading.

Set up k as a bit table

```
#define KSZ (10000000/64 + !!(10000000 % 63))
static uint64_t k[KSZ];

void init_k(void){
  // We can split this up to minimize cache misses, see below
  for (size_t i;i<10000000;++i)
    k[i/64] |= (uint64_t)((!!T_RDY[i]) & (!(~T_RWS[i] & M_RWS)) &((T_NUM[i] + P_LVL) <= P_LEN) ) << (i&63);
}
```

You can find the bit-index into k by searching for a non-zero 64-bit chunk, then using a bitscan to find the bit within that chunk:

```
size_t k2index(void){
  size_t i;
  for (i=0; i<KSZ;++i)
    if (k[i]) break;
  return 64 * i + __builtin_ctzll(k[i]);
}
```

You may want to split up your data reads so that you get sequential data access (each table is over 40=80MB as described) and don't get a cache miss on every single iteration.

```
#define KSZ (10000000/64 + !!(10000000%63))
static uint64_t k[KSZ], k0[KSZ], k1[KSZ]; //use calloc instead?

void init_k(void){
  //I split these up to minimize cache misses
  for (size_t i;i<10000000;++i)
    k[i/64] |= (uint64_t)(!!T_RDY[i]) << (i&63);
  for (size_t i;i<10000000;++i)
    k0[i/64] |= (uint64_t)(!(~T_RWS[i] & M_RWS)) << (i&63);
  for (size_t i;i<10000000;++i)
    k1[i/64] |= (uint64_t)((T_NUM[i] + P_LVL) <= P_LEN) << (i&63);

  //now combine them 64 bits at a time
  for (size_t i;i<KSZ;++i)
    k[i] &= k0[i];
  for (size_t i;i<KSZ;++i)
    k[i] &= k1[i];
}
```

If you split it up like this, you could also initialize (some of) them when you set up your other tables.  Or if the tables updated, you could update the k value as well.

Comment: You don't need k,k0,k1.  Use a nested loop to build up a `uint64_t` for 64x `(~T_RWS[i] & M_RWS)` values, then `&=` that into `k[i/64]`.  (And the first loop can accumulate a scalar tmp and use `=` instead of `|=` to avoid needing calloc).  Also, out-of-order exec might have an easier time with the init functions if you accumulated a 32-bit or even 16-bit chunk of the bitmap before storing, in case a serial dependency is a problem.  But C doesn't make it easy to access a bitmap with different chunk widths; I guess you'd need a union of `uint64_t[]` and `uint32_t[]`, and introduces endianness.

Comment: Also, a smaller chunk on init would make full unroll of the inner loop more practical, removing variable-count shifts, updating a bit-position, and loop overhead.  (Although with such large input elements not hot in cache, it might well still be memory bound.  But that would be more HT-friendly).

Comment: Reading 3 separate input streams and writing 1 output stream is probably best on modern x86 hardware.  You won't get significantly fewer cache misses from looping over each input array separately.  HW prefetch on Intel CPUs for example can track 1 forward and 1 backward stream per 4k page (L2 streamer).  And 4 streams is less than typical L1d associativity (8-way), although Skylake-client CPUs have 4-way associative L2 (down from 8-way).  So even when the inputs all alias the same set of L1d or L2 cache, they won't tend to cause conflict misses.  And each array has different element size.

Comment: BTW, AVX512 is pretty cool for turning compare results into bitmap arrays.  AVX512 SIMD compares put the result in a mask register, and you can do a zero-masked compare into another mask to AND together compare results for free.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the extra insight - I intended to mention threading as a reason to split it into 3 chunks like that, but then I  didn't want to write threaded code and omitted that point.  I also thought about accumulating a whole uint64 before storing - maybe in a future edit.  I don't have modern x86 hardware (not even avx2), so I tend to stick to things common to arm+neon and sse2.

Comment: The cache / prefetcher setup hasn't changed fundamentally since Nehalem; that's what "modern" means in this case.  Even Core2 is probably fine with just 4 memory streams; Intel's optimization manual still has old advice which recommends splitting loops with more than 4 write streams (I forget what they say about total streams including read).  Anyway yeah sure, you could thread the outer loops so each core works on a chunk of `k[]`, reading chunks of the input arrays.  If you're lucky, some of `k[]` will be in per-core private caches when you're done, ready for threaded search.

Comment: `<< (i%63);` should be `<< (i%64);`, right? `%64` gives numbers from 0 to 63 both included.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito  Correct, I intended to write &63, but most compilers will generate the same code - edited.  BTW  /64 is the same as >>6 for unsigned